# Thevenin Equivalent on this branch

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

Consider the following circuit schematic in which I'm tasked to determine its Thevenin equivalent:

[image]

I think I will use the method of putting a virtual voltage generator \$v_x \$ outputting a current \$i_x\$ and \$ R_{AB} = \frac{v_x}{i_x}\$
but I think \$ v_x = -3I_x - i_x + 4 - I_x \$ and \$ i_x + I_x = \frac{4-I_x}{1 \Omega}  \$

Comment: Wouldn't you just first Nortonize the 4 V, then combine the two resulting parallel resistors into 0.5 Ohm, then switch back to Thevenin of 2 V, 0.5 Ohm? Then the 0.5 Ohm adds to the 1 Ohm to get 1.5 Ohm. The 2V then adds to the dependent source, so that you have a final source of (2V - 3*(I+2)) or (-4V-3*I) and 1.5 Ohm? So with no load, I=0, so grounding B then A gives -4 V. Pulling 1 A gives -7 V. So (-7 V - (-4 V))/(1A-0A)=-3 Ohm. So you have -4V source and -3 ohm resistance?

Comment: @periblepsis so u are sayin V_th = V_ab = -4V and R_th = -3??

Comment: Yeah. That's what a quick glance says to me, anyway. How do you see it?

Comment: @periblepsis from which logic did you extract the factor to pull 1 A to get -7V?

Comment: I just `decided` on that because then the difference between 0 A and 1 A is 1. Which makes the division by the change in current `easy`. That's all. If you look at the voltage with no load you get some value. If you then look at the voltage when 1 A is being pulled out of that node, you get some different value. If you use 1 A then the voltage difference of the two cases is equal to the source impedance, since you are only dividing by 1 A and that doesn't change the value, only the units.

Comment: i see your method but i want a solution or hint using my approach of \$ v_x , i_x \$ @periblepsis

Comment: I don't know if your approach works. But I don't entirely follow it, either. So I probably can't really be of much help. Maybe if you wrote more....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149094/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-periblepsis).

Comment: Would that I have time for it. But I don't. Certainly not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your chat box:

> can you try to use KVL / KCL in that circuit to extract expressions
> for v_x interms of i_x?

Set \$V_b=0\:\text{V}\$ (ground it) and call the node shared by all three resistors as \$V\$. Then \$I_x=\frac{4\:\text{V}-V}{1\:\Omega}\$.

Leave \$V_a\$ open. Then there's no current through the branch including the dependent source so we can ignore it with KCL and simply write this KCL statement: \$\frac{V}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{V}{1\:\Omega}=\frac{4\:\text{V}}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{1\:\Omega}\$. That solves out as \$V=2\:\text{V}\$ (which would also be plainly obvious from the voltage divider.) And it readily follows that \$I_x=\frac{V}{1\:\Omega}=\frac{2\:\text{V}}{1\:\Omega}=2\:\text{A}\$. Given there's no current through the dependent source it also follows that \$V_{a_\text{ open}}=V-3\:\Omega\cdot I_x=2\:\text{V}-3\:\Omega\cdot 2\:\text{A}=-4\:\text{V}\$ and \$I_{a_\text{ open}}=0\:\text{A}\$.

Now short \$V_a\$ to ground. Now the KCL for node \$V\$ is \$\frac{V}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{V}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{V}{1\:\Omega}=\frac{4\:\text{V}}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{1\:\Omega}+\frac{3\:\Omega\,\cdot\, I_x}{1\:\Omega}\$ or just \$3\cdot V=4\:\text{V}+3\:\Omega\cdot I_x\$. But \$I_x=\frac{4\:\text{V}-V}{1\:\Omega}\$. So \$3\cdot V=4\:\text{V}+3\:\Omega\cdot \frac{4\:\text{V}-V}{1\:\Omega}\$ or \$V=\frac83\:\text{V}\$. So \$I_x=\frac43\:\text{A}\$ and the dependent source is \$+4\:\text{V}\$. This means that the shorted current, which is the current in the dependent source branch and pointing away from node \$V\$ and into ground, must be \$I_{a_\text{ shorted}}=\frac{V-\left(+4\:\text{V}\right)}{1\:\Omega}=-\frac43\:\text{A}\$. You should be able to see that the sum of the currents at node \$V\$ is zero, too, as KCL requires. Here, of course \$V_{a_\text{ shorted}}=0\:\text{V}\$.

So, the Thevenin impedance is \$\frac{V_{a_\text{ shorted}}-V_{a_\text{ open}}}{I_{a_\text{ shorted}}-I_{a_\text{ open}}}=\frac{0\:\text{V}-\left(-4\:\text{V}\right)}{-\frac43\:\text{A}-0\:\text{A}}=-3\:\Omega\$. The Thevenin voltage, of course, is just \$V_{a_\text{ open}}=-4\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: i see your approach but what if we only consider one case where we only have a virtual voltage generator \$v_x \$ producing the current \$ i_x \$ how do we  use that approach?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI I have no idea what you are asking to do. So I cannot help there. I can and did address the use of KCL. That I can understand and could do.

Comment: can you tell me what would be the maximal power transfert condition for such circuit -placing a resistor in the (AB) branch?